# What would be a good web based open source or low cost learing collaboration tool for high school students?

Tags: web-development, website-design, usability, social-media, open-source

Have about 60 kids that are working on a science projects in two groups. Each group would like a web portal where they can discuss topics relating to what they are building, post questions, pictures, videos, and keep their project going while not always in the same class room.

Also, I would like to host it personally and not have it accessible to the entire web.

What would you suggest for such a requirement?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to Blackboard? That's what a lot of college professors use, but it's commercial and I never liked the interface.

Comment: not really, not a big fan....good suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could always do a private http://www.drupal.org site using LAMP (or WAMP).

Comment: I like the "thousands of add-ons" as I am sure different needs will come up. How many hours would you estimate it would take for an average web developer to install this? Is there any code involved? Is the windows version difficult to install?

Comment: how does it compare to Joomla... looks very similar to me?

Comment: as soon as you get apache/mysql/php running it shouldn't take more than 30 mins to get a basic version running, about the joomla part it's similar but the API is much better and a lot more addons.

Answer (score 1):

I've used collabtive, it's an open source alternative to basecamp (a web based project collaboration software). It's pretty easy to use and can be self hosted.

Comment: Joshak, what made you choose this over more "popular" CMS like drupal or Joomla?

Comment: Drupal and Joomla are more general use where collabtive is specifically designed for project collaboration. Also Basecamp is a very popular commercial software which a large portion of companies I've worked with use and collabtive is very similar which makes it familiar for me as well as most people I need to share projects with.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) which supports uploading of files, forums, wiki and issue tracking. It's great for website/application project management, but I can see it working for your use, too.

It's open source and runs on Linux, Windows and MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

To get apache/mysql/php running you can just install bitnami WAMPstack http://bitnami.org/stack/wampstack . It's free like all installers there, and they install with the typical wizzards, great for people new to all these things.

You have [there](http://bitnami.org/stacks) as well stacks for the mentioned Redmine, Drupal, LAMP and you might be interested in Moodle stack (it's for eLearning, great for teachers)

Depending on what you want to do, it can be of use also Gallery, Coppermine gallery, Mediawiki...